# ROracle installation on Windows Server 2012

Tags: r, windows-server-2012-r2, roracle

I was able to successfully install 'ROracle' on my Windows desktop/laptop, but I am now having considerable trouble doing the same for a Windows Server. After following the installation instructions from [ROracle/INSTALL](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL), I moved on to installing the package itself from source.

```
> install.packages("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz", 
    repos=NULL, type="source")
#Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
#(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
#* installing *source* package 'ROracle' ...
#** package 'ROracle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
#/cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator/Downloads/oracle_client/instantclient_12_1/genezi.exe: 
error while loading shared libraries: ?: 
  cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have confirmed that the `genezi.exe` file does exist in the folder, but the directory path isn't correct. The prefix `/cygdrive/c/` is not in the path that I specified, it was added somewhere in the package instructions. Has anyone experienced this path addition?